# Adding 2 vectors using overloaded + in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to add 2 vectors using overloaded `+` operator. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/9329547 answer shows

> ```
> inline X operator+(X lhs, const X& rhs)
> {
>   lhs += rhs;
>   return lhs;
> }
> ```

My case is I want to pass 2 vectors to class, then a function will modify them and will add using another method and return it. Here is the code.

```
class VO
{
private:

const std::vector<double> &vec1;
const std::vector<double> &vec2;

public:
VO (const std::vector<double> &x, const std::vector<double> &y): vec1(x), vec2(y) {}

std::vector<double> operator + (const std::vector<double> &, const std::vector<double> &) {}

std::vector<double> foo(....) 
{ 
//vectors vec1, vec 2 are modified here then want to add them
std::vector<double> v3 = vec1 + vec2;
return v3;
}
};

int main()
{
std::vector<double> a={1,2,3,4,5}, b={9,8,7,6,5},c;
VO obj(a,b);
c=obj.foo();
return 0;
}
```

In this case, I am not sure how can I use `this` to add 2 vectors.

Edit:

I can create `vectorAdd` method in the class, pass 2 vectors and get addition. But I want to use operator `+` for that. Operator `+` is overloaded in many scientific libraries to add vectors (arrays).

Edit 2:

If I use my original code, I get error `error C2804 binary operator + has too many parameters`. I am trying to add 2 vectors such that if `a={1,2,3,4,5}, b={9,8,7,6,5}`, then `a+b = {1+9, 2+8, 3+7, 4+6, 5+5} = {10,10,10,10,10}`

Comment: @Borgleader That looks like merging two arrays. My question is different one.

Comment: it should be a free function. The operator you wrote would be called like that `obj.operator+(a,b);` and you cannot do `a+b`.

Comment: this maybe makes a better dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: @user463035818, please see my (updated) question. I already linked that question.

Comment: oh, didnt see that. The problem is that you do something different in your code than what that answer suggests. You implemented `operator+` as member function of `OV`, but `operator+` for vectors can only be a free function.. that being said, it is the correct dupe

Comment: its a bit hard to find, but if you search for "According to our rules of thumb, + and its companions should be non-members, while their ..." you will find the relevant paragraph

Comment: btw I voted to reopen because the currently assigned dupe really is about something different

Comment: this->operator+(a, b).  thise library you talk about do not use std::vector as their operating class, because they need operator+ as a free function for mathematical vector type. std::vector is a dynamic array type , inept for this use unless you make a class-wrapper

Comment: Which `+` do you mean -- appending or element-wise?  That is why there is no default `operator+` on `vector`.  Second, you want a `+` that only works within a method of the class?  No can do; `+` within a method of the class doesn't look for member `+`, it looks at the `+` on the two types being added.  You need to clarify what you want so an appoach can be found that solves your problem; I can think of a dozen solutions to a dozen different problems, but I cannot determine which of those dozen problems are actually a way to solve your problem (if any).

Comment: Why is it important that the vectors are added _using another method_? Why would you want a method called `operator+` when the only reason for using that name is the syntactic sugar you specifically _don't_ get in this case?

Comment: @Useless there is vector addition, then subtraction, then multiplication and so on. Imagine you want to do `x=a*y+z`, `x,y,z` are `std::vectors` and `a` is `int`. "syntactic sugar" is much needed.

Comment: Yes, I understand the value of syntactic sugar. I don't understand why you insist on putting `operator+` in a class unrelated to the things you want to add. I don't understand what `V0` is supposed to be _for_, or how you expect the compiler to guess where you want it to get `operator+` _from_. Are you just using it as a namespace?

Comment: @Useless I was confused, I will put `operator+` in another class. Purpose of class `VO` is to modify the input vectors. What I don't understand is why I cannot take 2 arguments to `operator+`. I mentioned that in Edit 2.

Comment: Wait, why are you putting the operator in a class **at all**? Not _why are you putting it in `V0` instead of `W1`_ or whatever. What do you think classes are _for_? They're not just random assortments of functions. If you want `vector operator+(vector,vector)` to work, you can't alter `std::vector`, so it must be a free function. Not in any class.

Comment: @Useless I was thinking to put together similar functions on vectors such as `+,-,*`, that's why I thought I should create a class and have all these together. But from your comment it looks like it doesn't work that way. By the way, can you explain more on:  `if you want vector operator+(vector,vector) to work, you can't alter std::vector`. How someone can alter `std::vector` if put in a class and if put as a "free" function?

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but you seem pretty confused about how and why to use operator overloading.

> I am trying to add 2 vectors using overloaded + operator

OK, the purpose of this overloaded operator is that you can type

```
vector<double> a, b, c;
// ... populate a and b ...
c = a + b;
```

*as if* `vector<double>` were a primitive type like `int` or a simple `double`.

The *whole point* is to get the same syntax for built-in and user-defined types, so that later we can write generic code that works identically for both. For example, [`std::plus`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) and [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) work for *any* type with `operator+` defined, whether you're adding integers or vectors or something else.

For this to work (and operator overloading to be worthwhile), your custom `operator+` must be found by the usual name lookup rules when you write `a + b`.

Then you say

> I want to pass 2 vectors to class, then a function will modify them and will add using another method

but using a class method instead of a free function doesn't satisfy the requirements above. `V0::operator+` won't be found when you type `a + b`. (In fact `V0::operator+` can anyway only be a method for adding something to a `V0`, because it must be non-static if it is a method, and so the left-hand-side will always be a `V0` object).

If you still want addition to be a method of `V0`, there's no reason to call it `operator+`, because the syntax won't be the same anyway.

Conversely if you *do* want the same syntax, it should be a free function in order for the name lookup to work.

You say you want to overload the operator because it is *overloaded in many scientific libraries*, but that doesn't explain wanting it to be a method of a class other than the type you're adding

- if you want to use one of those libraries and provide it an `operator+` to use, then putting the operator inside an unrelated class won't achieve anything. How will the library know it's supposed to call `V0::operator+` when adding two `vector<double>`? That's not the way anything works
- if you want to imitate the style of those libraries, the only `operator+` associated with your `V0` type would be used to add `V0` instances. And it should still be a free function.

Comment: OK. I will put the `operator+` in a separate class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible implementation of vector addition, using the guidelines you linked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T>& operator+=(std::vector<T> &lhs, const std::vector<T> &rhs) {
    typedef std::vector<T>::size_type size_type;
    if (lhs.size() != rhs.size())
        throw std::length_error("vectors must be same size to add");

    for (size_type i = 0; i < lhs.size(); ++i)
        lhs[i] += rhs[i];
    return lhs;
}

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> operator+ (std::vector<T> lhs, const std::vector<T> &rhs) {
    typedef std::vector<T>::size_type size_type;
    if (lhs.size() != rhs.size())
        throw std::length_error("vectors must be same size to add");
    return lhs += rhs;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> a = { 1,2,3,4,5 }, b = { 9,8,7,6,5 }, c;
    c = a + b;
    for (auto x : c)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> > 10 10 10 10 10

You could define a math vector class which has-a std::vector (because no virtual destructor), and define the math operators on that, so that you can't accidentally call this operator on std::vectors which are not intended to be math vectors. Personally, I would just get one of those math libraries you mentioned, and use it. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Your `operator +` can be simplified: typedef unused, and check already done in `+=`.

Comment: So, the same class cannot have `foo()` and `operator +`, referring to my question.

Comment: Well, you could, but ... VO::foo and VO::operator+ seem completely unrelated, because foo does other stuff, and I don't even know how to add two different instances of VO.

Answer (score 1):

A vector is a fixed type.  You should not add `+` to it.

You can extend vector like this:

```
template<class T>
struct my_vector:std::vector<T> {
  using std::vector<T>::vector; // get vector's constructors

  my_vector& operator+=( my_vector const& rhs )& {
    if (size() < rhs.size()) resize(rhs.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rhs.size(); ++i)
      (*this)[i] += rhs[i];
    return *this;
  }
  friend my_vector operator+( my_vector lhs, my_vector const& rhs ) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
  my_vector& operator*=( my_vector const& rhs )& {
    if (size() < rhs.size()) resize(rhs.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rhs.size(); ++i)
      (*this)[i] *= rhs[i];
    return *this;
  }
  friend my_vector operator*( my_vector lhs, my_vector const& rhs ) {
    lhs *= rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
};
```

Now, use `my_vector<double>` instead of `std::vector<double>`.

Now, you could add this `operator+` in the namespace where you are doing the work, but that generally isn't a good idea.  Operations on types should be part of the type or in the type's namespace to avoid surprises.